# onActivityResult and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: workaround?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-stack

Here is my scenario: I have a series of `Activity`. I set a timeout on those `Activity` that will disconnect the user in case it get inactive for a moment. But I want to redirect the user to its last screen in case he log

When I'm disconnecting the user I'm calling this:

```
public void restartFromLoginActivity(boolean saveCurrentState, String previousLoggedUserId) {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
    Intent intent = new Intent(CERHISApplication.this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    if(saveCurrentState && currentActivity != null){
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(ApplicationController.KEY_PREVIOUSLY_LOGGED_USER_ID, previousLoggedUserId);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, ApplicationController.RC_LOGIN);
    }
    else
        startActivity(intent);

    if(currentActivity != null)
        currentActivity.finish();
}
```

And in my `LoginActivity` I check if the userId is the same, if so I try to call redirect the user via `onActivityResult` like this:

```
if (getCallingActivity() != null && userId.equals(previouslyLoggedUserId)) 
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
else
    ApplicationController.startHomeActivity(this);
```

But this doesn't work because I set the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to my intent. As said in the documentation:

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched.

Which I understand, an `Activity` can only receive results from an `Activity` from the task. But I need to set this flag otherwise the user would be able to get back in the `Activity stack` by pressing the back button.

Is their any workaround to combine both the **clearing** of the stack to avoid the user to get back Activities before he logs in again and the **redirect** behavior I would like to introduce?

Any idea is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use resultreceiver may work fine for your design